# JavaScript Regex is not validating

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex, smarty

I have a problem with my code. It should display red inputbox if I don't match regex else it should appear as green inputbox.

```js
function IsValid(pole, regex) {
  if (regex.test(pole.value)) {
    pole.className = "ok";
    return true;
  } else {
    pole.className = "chyba";
    return false;
  }
}

function OnSubmit(form) {
  if (IsValid(form.filter_date, dateReg)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  var filter_date = document.getElementById("filter_date");
  dateReg = /^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/;
  filter_date.onblur = function() {
    IsValid(this, dateReg);
  }
  document.forms("filter_form").onsubmit = function() {
    return OnSubmit(this);
  }
}
```

```css
.ok {
  background-color: red;
}
.chyba {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<form id="filter_form" name="filter_form" action="" method="post">
  <table class="filter_training" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    ....
    <input type="text" id="filter_date" name="filter_date" placeholder="01-01-1970" />....
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

**1).** The main problem is that `onsubmit` handler should be bound this way:

```
document.forms.filter_form.onsubmit = function(){
    return OnSubmit(this); 
}
```

because `document.forms("filter_form")` will throw an error since `document.forms` is a collection, not a function.

**2).** Another minor issue is that you confused colors, it should be:

```
.ok { background-color: green; }
.chyba { background-color: red; }
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fjm9yhdx/

Answer (score 1):

It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/d8swfdbj/

```
.ok{ color: green;}
.chyba{ color: red; }
```

Your green/red classes are simply the wrong way round.

Comment: Yeah I am blind but main problem is that it load page. It should stay on this page till I put right combination to my inputbox. Thanks